# Touch events happen befor an activity is displayed

Tags: android, events, android-activity

In my program I have 2 activities. First one contains a keyboard for Pin and a second one which is displayed right after.

When an user enters 4 pin numbers second activity starts. But the problem is if the user clicks too many times on keyboard (more than 5 click), some touch events are propagated to next activity, while the first activity is still displayed.

This behavior is also somewhat device depended, to me it occurs on Asus Memo 10 tablet with Android 4.3, but it doesn't appear on nexus 7 with android 4.4.

Is there anyway to prevent click events being propagated to another while the first is still active?
And if that is not possible is there a way to detect when is activity is fully displayed so that I can disable click events until it is displayed.
Because I would really prefer not to have any arbitrary delay after pin input.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you are doing,  I think you need to review the Android Activity lifecycle.  You can use the various lifecycle methods to control when actions happen.  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Do you use the soft input keyboard ?

Comment: No pin keyboard is a custom view. Neither hard or sft keyboard are used

Comment: Check your condition properly.. and without the code can't help you

Answer (score 0):

`onStart()` method is what you're looking for to disable click events, but your aproach is not a good thing, maybe you should consider to have something like "Done" button, which user will click after he finishes his input? It can also be useful because you can write code to check pin for lenght or validate

Comment: Done button isn't a option, since it would mean 1 extra click for the user (this app is a pos program so all interactions must be as fast as possible).
Also there is validation, but it doesn't influence this issue at all.

I understand that I can disable touch event onStart(), but when do I enable them back. How can i know when is activity drawn on screen (with contained fragment if possible)

Comment: you can use __view.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // code you want to run when view is visible for the first time
    }
  }
)__ in your __OnCreateView__ of fragment

Comment: Sorry for the long time to reply.
This is no longer an issue since we decided to use another approach an move the fragment from the first activity to second on.

We use sugar orm with which you can get data from database even from main GUI thread and we loaded a lot of data in onCreateView method of the fragment. And my guess is that this blocked propagatin of the events until data was loaded and the events could be propagated again (although I haven't tested this).